# Force Typescript Map key/value to be of a certain type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I wish to create a map in which the key is a string and the value is an object, where each object a certain set of values described by mapValue.

```
type mapValue
{
  first: string;
  second: boolean;
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, use an `interface` instead of `type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways of doing that and it sounds like you need to read some TypeScript docs to get a better understanding of what you're doing. If you're coming from JavaScript, I recommend [this short read](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html) (and then read the rest of the site... ).

It's easy to use your type in another type:

```
type MapValue = {
  first: string;
  second: boolean;
};

// when you know the expected properties
type AnotherThing = {
  id: string;
  content: string;
  thing: MapValue;
};

// when you want a flexible object type indexed by strings, with a fixed value
type AnotherThing = {
  [key: string]: MapValue;
};

// bonus points - use a typescript utility for a shorthand version of the above
type AnotherThing = Record<string, MapValue>;
```

Comment: Yeah I found the answer a few minutes after I posted but didn't know what to change this question to and couldn't delete it. It's correct though so I marked it.